# How would you reduce the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation to one paragraph?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm working on a project where I must describe the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation in a short amount of time. As such, I will have to use only the vital parts of the equation and its usages.

Now, I have been researching non-stop (!) about the equation for the past week or so, and have a "sort of" grasp on what it entails. However, I am curious about what YOU all think of it. There could easily be vital points which I miss out on, which I would not want to do.

How would you reduce the rocket equation, or describe it, in just one sentence or paragraph?

(And don't worry, this isn't a text-based project. I won't plagiarize your explanations! ^^;)

I'm not sure if I should be asking this here or on the Physics stackexchange. But still, thank you all in advance! Very curious to see a paraphrased explanation of this rather large subject.

Comment: The differential equation is about one line long, its solution makes two more lines. Yes, I guess that fits in one paragraph.

Comment: you might include the equation and at least try to give a go at it, then others can help. so far no effort has been shown except too many words of promise, it needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Is the Wikipedia article [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) helpful?

Comment: @jimjim yes, that's a very good point. I should've thought of that before I wrote the question. Let me write something up now...

Answer (score 0):

Using the momentum equation:
$$F=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}$$
you can differentiate this to get:
$$F=\frac{dm}{dt}v+m\frac{dv}{dt}$$
if you do this for a discrete period of time you get:
$$\Delta v=\frac{dv}{dt}\Delta t$$
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=\frac{m_f-m_0}{\Delta t}$$
so I would approach it this way